# How to generate a random word with a number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking for a method to generate a invite code. I would prefer the code not looks like garbled text: JakSj12

But rather more like heroku, using a fun word with 3 numbers.

```
lightspeed131 or happy124, jetski99
```

How can I build a method that takes a list of words, maybe 100? and randomly assigns 3 numbers to them?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other answers given here are a bit slow, since they shuffle their lists on every call.  Here's something a bit faster:

```
def wordwithnumber(words)
   words[rand(words.length)]+(rand(900)+100).to_s()
end

wordwithnumber(["lightspeed", "happy", "jetski"])
```

This gives you three digits every time, if you want a number from 0 to 999 modify the rand() call accordingly.

Comment: @AnApprentice, if that's the selected answer then you only wanted one word, the question said "assigns 3 numbers to them", I guess you meant "to it".

Comment: @rwat Note that as of Ruby 1.9 you can use `words.sample` in place of `words[rand(words.length)]`.

Comment: @Phrogz Cool, that's a handy function I didn't know about :)

Answer (score 2):

```
def random_name(words, number = nil)
  number ||= rand(999)

  words.sample.to_s + number.to_s # concatenate a random word and the number
end

# example:
random_name(["lightspeed", "happy"]) # lightspeedXXX, happyXXX (where XXX is a random number)
random_name(["lightspeed", "happy"], 5) # lightspeed5, happy5
```

Comment: You might want that to be `rand(899) + 100` if you want guaranteed three digit numbers.

Comment: @tadman Yep, +1. However, in the example he provided (heroku), there are numbers which have only two digits, so I inferred that they may be any number, provided they have at max 3 digits.

Comment: if you want 3 digits you could also do `sprintf("%s%03d", words.sample.to_s, number)`

Answer (score 2):

Always 3 different numbers? not very efficient but simple:

```
words.zip((100..999).to_a.shuffle).map(&:join)
```

If you don't mind getting repeated numbers (I guess not):

```
words.map { |word| word + 3.times.map { rand(10) }.join }
```

Or simply in Ruby 1.9:

```
words.map { |word| word + Random.new.rand(100..999).to_s }
```

([edit] This generate 100 words with numbers, which is what I understood. )

Answer (score 1):

I would use following (very readable IMHO) solution:

```
names = %w[tinky\ winky dipsy laa-laa po]

def random_name(names)
  [names, (100..999).to_a].collect(&:sample).join
end

3.times.collect { random_name(names) }
# => ["dipsy147", "dipsy990", "po756"]
```

---

More memory friendly solution:

```
def random_name(names)
  @numbers ||= (100..999).to_a
  [names, @numbers].collect(&:sample).join
end
```

Comment: "Further, the name with the number 100 will always be the first name in the array." - Can you please explain?

Comment: That "Further..." statement by me was a mistake on my part. I misread your code. I have deleted my comment and removed my downvote (though there's still no good reason to create a 900-element array just to pick a value randomly).

Comment: This dependents of the app/code. In a rake task or other background job, I don't see a problem. And you can even add a cache for the numbers. Will edit my solution.

Comment: You're right that the performance and memory will probably be fine, but I don't see why you would go to the effort of `(100..999).to_a.sample` instead of simply `rand(900)+100`. Just for readability?

Comment: Yes, Ruby is a sexy language for me. Readability is very important, otherwise I would switch back to C or another "ugly" language.

Answer (score 1):

```
def random_word_and_number( words, max=999 )
  "%s%0#{max.to_s.length}d" % [ words.sample, rand(max+1) ]
end 

(1..4).map{ random_word_and_number( %w[ foo bar jim jam ] ) }
#=> ["jim048", "bar567", "jim252", "foo397"]
```

Let's you specify an arbitrary maximum value while ensuring that all answers have the same number of digits.